# Atiyah-McDonald Exercise 4.11

Tags: commutative-algebra, modules

> 1. If $\mathfrak{p}$ is a minimal prime ideal of a ring $A$, then $S_\mathfrak{p}(0)$ is the smallest $\mathfrak{p}$-primary ideal.
> 2. Let $\mathfrak{a}$ be the intersection of the ideals $S_{\mathfrak{p}}(0)$ as $\mathfrak{p}$ runs through the minimal prime ideals of $A$. If the zero ideal is decomposible, then $\mathfrak{a} = 0$ iff every prime ideal of $0$ is isolated.

Notation: $S_{\mathfrak{p}}(0)=\text{Ker}(A\to A_{\mathfrak{p}})$.

1. I know $r(S_{\mathfrak{p}}(0))=\mathfrak{p}$. I tried to show this is primary by showing if $xy\in S_{\mathfrak{p}}(0)$ and $y\notin S_{\mathfrak{p}}(0)$ then $x\in S_{\mathfrak{p}}(0)$ but I don't know how to prove.
2. Suppose every prime ideal of $0$ is isolated. Then every prime ideal is a minimal prime ideal of $A$ as every prime ideal contains $0$. Hence $\mathfrak{a} = \bigcap_{\mathfrak{p}}S_{\mathfrak{p}}(0) = 0$. Now suppose $\mathfrak{a}=0$ and there is a prime ideal $\mathfrak{p}$ of $0$ such that $\mathfrak{p}$ is embedded. Then there is some prime ideal $\mathfrak{p}'$ of $0$ such that $\mathfrak{p}'\subset\mathfrak{p}$. Hence, $S_{\mathfrak{p}'}(0)\supset S_{\mathfrak{p}}(0)$. From here, I don't know how to get further. Could you give any hint?

Answer (score 1):

for the first part you have to prove that $x^n\in S_p(0)$ not $x$. and then use $\sqrt{S_p(0)}=p$ which means that for every $x\in p$,$x^n\in S_p(0)$.

for the second part I think you are wrong that every prime ideal is minimal,every associated prime ideal is minimal, and from this you can conclude the first direction, for the other direction use that the set of radicals of the primes that apear in primary decomposition is equal to the set of associated prime and the fact you mentioned about radical of $S_p(0)$.(and of course the uniqueness of primary decomposition.) remember that you are only considering $S_p$ for minimal prime ideals

Comment: 1) Yes but still, I don't know how to prove it. And I don't understand the point of $x^n\in S_p(0)$. $xy\in S_p(0)\subset p$ so $(xy)^n\in S_p(0)$ but $xy$ is already in $S_p(0)$.
2) Every associated prime ideal of $0$ is same as minimal prime ideal over $0$ so I think it's all prime ideal.

Comment: 1)for the first one do you understand why if $x,y\not \in S_p(0)$ both $x,y\in p$? just write the definition and after that use the fact about radical.2)I don't understand take $\mathbb{Z}$ then it has only one minimal(or associated) prime ideal and satisfy the conditions.)

Comment: the point of $x^n$ is that it is possible that  at the end you get a p-primary ideal and not the p itself.(I think you are basically claiming every primary ideal is prime!)

Comment: I don't understand the comment about 1). what do you mean $x,y\notin S_p(0)$ both $x,y\in p$?

Comment: $xy\in S_p$ means that there is an element $t$ outside $p$ such that $txy=0$.now if $y\not \in S_p$ it means that $tx$ must be in $p$ which means that $x$ must be in $p$ which means that $x^n\in S_p$ because $\sqrt S_p=p$

Comment: Why $y\notin S_p(0)$ implies $tx\in p$? I think you're assuming $y\in S_p(0)\iff y\in p$ right?

Comment: no! if $tx\not \in p$ then because $txy=0$, $y$ would be in the kernel of the map $A\to A_p$ almost by definition!